# How can I make my social sharing button pop up responsive on mobile device

Tags: responsive-design, media-queries

I have a social sharing button that I would like to behave responsively on iPhone and other mobile devices. The news blog I have it on is a responsive blog, but the social sharing button is not scaling appropriately. Any help will do. Thank you.

Comment: some live code or url?

Comment: Go to http://www.chattaboom.com on your mobile device. See social sharing button below article 'Boom It' See how it pop up off screen to right. Thanks Danko